# How to change the cmd's current-dir using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-8, command-line-interface

I read some file using `PowerShell`, and change current dir accordingly, but all I can do is change the current `PowerShell`'s current dir, not the caller's dir (the cmd.exe environment that called that ps1 file). Things I tried:

```
powershell ch-dir.ps1 | cd
```

(won't work, obviously, since `CD` is internal command)

```
powershell cd $myDir
```

(changes current dir in `PowerShell`, but when script exits, the `cmd` environment still in original dir)

I really hope I won't need to find the script's caller process (the cmd), and make a change in it's cur-dir by-force... (or even worse - to save the dir I want in some env-var and then `cd %my_var%` since it would require two lines of command)

Comment: Pretty sure it is not possible to reach back into the parent process and change it's environment. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: You can get current process's parent, and I think that you can also change any process's current-dir, but that's not the issue here...

Comment: Like *EBGreen* said, it doesn't work that way. What are you trying to achieve by changing the caller's working directory?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, what part doesn't work that way ? finding the parent process or changing its work-dir ?

Comment: Finding the parent process is easy.  Changing another process's working directory is not. Heck I'm not sure that can be done - short of some invasive technique like DLL injection.

Comment: @KeithHill - it's possible to write to the [PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block), but this thread is going the wrong path... I just want some piping or env-var solution, not messing with win-internals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this meets your needs, but if you set it up so that the only output from your powershell script is your desired new working directory, you could do this:

```
c:\>for /F %i IN ('powershell -noprofile -command "write-output 'c:\users'" ') DO @cd %i
c:\Users>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cmd prompt is hosting your powershell session, unless you can figure out a way to return an exit code to the prompt that will (on exit code 99999) change directory to (predefined values, switch?). As far as powershell is concerned they're different processes.

Heres a good example for you to try:
Open a cmd prompt. 
Open task manager, find cmd.exe
In your cmd prompt type Powershell
View powershell as a different process (check the PID.)
End the powershell process. Watch what happens.

Alternatively, if you need something run from cmd in a specific directory based on logic in your powershell script, you can invoke it with a `cmd /c` from within Powershell.

Comment: yes, they run in two different processes, I know, but I thought there may be a way to pipe commands or something

Comment: Check out the answer that zdan provided.